# How to distort an image using 4 points in screen space in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics, transformation

Is there a way to distort an image using 4 points where the 4 points will correspond to the corners of an image?

Something like this:

[image]

Ignore the mid points and the center point. Here even though the image looks like it's deformed in 3d, it's not in my case. It's just like modifying a 2d rectangle polygon on screen where the image that fills the rectangle conforms to the modified shape/polygon, since both has 4 vertices and 4 edges.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Will a simple SkewTransform not do what you want?

Comment: Skew would constrain verts in pairs, right? I need each of them to be independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Charles Petzold's technique described here:

- [Non-Affine Transforms in 2D?](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/08/250638.html)

The second sample is a demo of exactly what you are describing.